# How to cross-compile a rust application for ARM which uses Rocket web-server and requires nightly toolchain using Yocto?

Tags: rust, cross-compiling, yocto, rust-cargo, bitbake

I want to compile myRustApp which uses Rocket webserver in my meta layer. The issu I'm having is that openembedded does not support nightly release of Rust, which is required to run Rocket web-server.
The alternative was to use [meta-rust](https://github.com/meta-rust/meta-rust), but it got me no where, because if I understand correctly the meta layer only supports native builds.
So I ended up using [meta-rust-bin](https://github.com/rust-embedded/meta-rust-bin) layer with pre-built nightly toolchain.

I was able to build nightly by executing `./build-new-version.sh nightly` under meta-rust-bin.

After all this my recipe build by bitbake returns an Error:

```
WARNING: /home/jonas/project/sources/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/rust/rust-cross_1.59.0.bb: Exception during build_dependencies for TARGET_LLVM_FEATURES
WARNING: /home/jonas/project/sources/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/rust/rust-cross_1.59.0.bb: Error during finalise of /home/jonas/project/sources/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/rust/rust-cross_1.59.0.bb
ERROR: ExpansionError during parsing /home/jonas/project/sources/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/rust/rust-cross_1.59.0.bb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Var <TARGET_LLVM_FEATURES>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jonas/project/sources/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/rust/rust-common.inc", line 117, in llvm_features(d=<bb.data_smart.DataSmart object at 0x7fe03b341f60>):
         return ','.join(llvm_features_from_tune(d) +
    >                    llvm_features_from_cc_arch(d) +
                         llvm_features_from_target_fpu(d))
  File "/home/jonas/project/sources/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/rust/rust-common.inc", line 36, in llvm_features_from_tune(d=<bb.data_smart.DataSmart object at 0x7fe03b341f60>):

    >    if target_is_armv7(d):
             f.append('+v7')
bb.data_smart.ExpansionError: Failure expanding variable TARGET_LLVM_FEATURES, expression was ${@llvm_features(d)} which triggered exception NameError: name 'target_is_armv7' is not defined
The variable dependency chain for the failure is: TARGET_LLVM_FEATURES

ERROR: Parsing halted due to errors, see error messages above
WARNING: /home/jonas/project/sources/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/rust/rust-cross-canadian_1.59.0.bb: Exception during build_dependencies for TARGET_LLVM_FEATURES
WARNING: /home/jonas/project/sources/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/rust/rust-cross-canadian_1.59.0.bb: Error during finalise of /home/jonas/project/sources/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-devtools/rust/rust-cross-canadian_1.59.0.bb
```

My question is:

1. What causes this error I'm getting? How can I fix it?
2. Did someone already tried to cross-compile Rust nightly apps? Are there any examples anywhere?

My Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "MyRustApp"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
rocket = "0.4.10"
rocket_cors = "0.5.1"
serde = "1.0"
serde_json = "1.0"
serde_derive = "1.0"

[dependencies.rocket_contrib]
version = "0.4.10"
default-features = false
features = ["json"]

[profile.release]
strip = true
opt-level = "z" 
lto = true
```

My recipe generated by cargo bitbake:

```
# Auto-Generated by cargo-bitbake 0.3.16
#
inherit cargo

# If this is git based prefer versioned ones if they exist
# DEFAULT_PREFERENCE = "-1"

# how to get strain-webserver could be as easy as but default to a git checkout:
# SRC_URI += "crate://crates.io/MyRustApp/0.1.0"
SRC_URI += "git://git@bitbucket.org/work/MyRustApp.git;protocol=ssh;nobranch=1;branch=main"
SRCREV = "xxx"
S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
CARGO_SRC_DIR = ""
PV:append = ".AUTOINC+d2562d3c92"

# please note if you have entries that do not begin with crate://
# you must change them to how that package can be fetched
SRC_URI += " \
    crate://crates.io/aead/0.3.2 \
    crate://crates.io/aes-gcm/0.8.0 \
    crate://crates.io/aes-soft/0.6.4 \
    crate://crates.io/aes/0.6.0 \
    crate://crates.io/aesni/0.10.0 \
    crate://crates.io/aho-corasick/0.7.20 \
    crate://crates.io/atty/0.2.14 \
    crate://crates.io/autocfg/1.1.0 \
    crate://crates.io/base64/0.13.1 \
    crate://crates.io/base64/0.9.3 \
    crate://crates.io/bitflags/1.3.2 \
    crate://crates.io/block-buffer/0.9.0 \
    crate://crates.io/byteorder/1.4.3 \
    crate://crates.io/cfg-if/0.1.10 \
    crate://crates.io/cfg-if/1.0.0 \
    crate://crates.io/cipher/0.2.5 \
    crate://crates.io/cookie/0.11.5 \
    crate://crates.io/cpufeatures/0.2.5 \
    crate://crates.io/cpuid-bool/0.2.0 \
    crate://crates.io/crypto-mac/0.10.1 \
    crate://crates.io/ctr/0.6.0 \
    crate://crates.io/devise/0.2.1 \
    crate://crates.io/devise_codegen/0.2.1 \
    crate://crates.io/devise_core/0.2.1 \
    crate://crates.io/digest/0.9.0 \
    crate://crates.io/filetime/0.2.18 \
    crate://crates.io/form_urlencoded/1.1.0 \
    crate://crates.io/fsevent-sys/2.0.1 \
    crate://crates.io/fsevent/0.4.0 \
    crate://crates.io/fuchsia-zircon-sys/0.3.3 \
    crate://crates.io/fuchsia-zircon/0.3.3 \
    crate://crates.io/generic-array/0.14.6 \
    crate://crates.io/getrandom/0.2.8 \
    crate://crates.io/ghash/0.3.1 \
    crate://crates.io/glob/0.3.0 \
    crate://crates.io/hashbrown/0.12.3 \
    crate://crates.io/hermit-abi/0.1.19 \
    crate://crates.io/hkdf/0.10.0 \
    crate://crates.io/hmac/0.10.1 \
    crate://crates.io/httparse/1.8.0 \
    crate://crates.io/hyper/0.10.16 \
    crate://crates.io/idna/0.1.5 \
    crate://crates.io/idna/0.3.0 \
    crate://crates.io/indexmap/1.9.2 \
    crate://crates.io/inotify-sys/0.1.5 \
    crate://crates.io/inotify/0.7.1 \
    crate://crates.io/iovec/0.1.4 \
    crate://crates.io/itoa/1.0.4 \
    crate://crates.io/kernel32-sys/0.2.2 \
    crate://crates.io/language-tags/0.2.2 \
    crate://crates.io/lazycell/1.3.0 \
    crate://crates.io/libc/0.2.137 \
    crate://crates.io/log/0.3.9 \
    crate://crates.io/log/0.4.17 \
    crate://crates.io/matches/0.1.9 \
    crate://crates.io/memchr/2.5.0 \
    crate://crates.io/mime/0.2.6 \
    crate://crates.io/mio-extras/2.0.6 \
    crate://crates.io/mio/0.6.23 \
    crate://crates.io/miow/0.2.2 \
    crate://crates.io/net2/0.2.38 \
    crate://crates.io/notify/4.0.17 \
    crate://crates.io/num_cpus/1.14.0 \
    crate://crates.io/opaque-debug/0.3.0 \
    crate://crates.io/pear/0.1.5 \
    crate://crates.io/pear_codegen/0.1.5 \
    crate://crates.io/percent-encoding/1.0.1 \
    crate://crates.io/percent-encoding/2.2.0 \
    crate://crates.io/polyval/0.4.5 \
    crate://crates.io/ppv-lite86/0.2.17 \
    crate://crates.io/proc-macro2/0.4.30 \
    crate://crates.io/proc-macro2/1.0.47 \
    crate://crates.io/quote/0.6.13 \
    crate://crates.io/quote/1.0.21 \
    crate://crates.io/rand/0.8.5 \
    crate://crates.io/rand_chacha/0.3.1 \
    crate://crates.io/rand_core/0.6.4 \
    crate://crates.io/redox_syscall/0.2.16 \
    crate://crates.io/regex-syntax/0.6.28 \
    crate://crates.io/regex/1.7.0 \
    crate://crates.io/rocket/0.4.11 \
    crate://crates.io/rocket_codegen/0.4.11 \
    crate://crates.io/rocket_contrib/0.4.11 \
    crate://crates.io/rocket_cors/0.5.2 \
    crate://crates.io/rocket_http/0.4.11 \
    crate://crates.io/ryu/1.0.11 \
    crate://crates.io/safemem/0.3.3 \
    crate://crates.io/same-file/1.0.6 \
    crate://crates.io/serde/1.0.147 \
    crate://crates.io/serde_derive/1.0.147 \
    crate://crates.io/serde_json/1.0.89 \
    crate://crates.io/sha2/0.9.9 \
    crate://crates.io/slab/0.4.7 \
    crate://crates.io/smallvec/1.10.0 \
    crate://crates.io/state/0.4.2 \
    crate://crates.io/subtle/2.4.1 \
    crate://crates.io/syn/0.15.44 \
    crate://crates.io/syn/1.0.103 \
    crate://crates.io/time/0.1.44 \
    crate://crates.io/tinyvec/1.6.0 \
    crate://crates.io/tinyvec_macros/0.1.0 \
    crate://crates.io/toml/0.4.10 \
    crate://crates.io/traitobject/0.1.0 \
    crate://crates.io/typeable/0.1.2 \
    crate://crates.io/typenum/1.15.0 \
    crate://crates.io/unicase/1.4.2 \
    crate://crates.io/unicase/2.6.0 \
    crate://crates.io/unicase_serde/0.1.0 \
    crate://crates.io/unicode-bidi/0.3.8 \
    crate://crates.io/unicode-ident/1.0.5 \
    crate://crates.io/unicode-normalization/0.1.22 \
    crate://crates.io/unicode-xid/0.1.0 \
    crate://crates.io/universal-hash/0.4.1 \
    crate://crates.io/url/1.7.2 \
    crate://crates.io/url/2.3.1 \
    crate://crates.io/version_check/0.1.5 \
    crate://crates.io/version_check/0.9.4 \
    crate://crates.io/walkdir/2.3.2 \
    crate://crates.io/wasi/0.10.0+wasi-snapshot-preview1 \
    crate://crates.io/wasi/0.11.0+wasi-snapshot-preview1 \
    crate://crates.io/winapi-build/0.1.1 \
    crate://crates.io/winapi-i686-pc-windows-gnu/0.4.0 \
    crate://crates.io/winapi-util/0.1.5 \
    crate://crates.io/winapi-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu/0.4.0 \
    crate://crates.io/winapi/0.2.8 \
    crate://crates.io/winapi/0.3.9 \
    crate://crates.io/windows-sys/0.42.0 \
    crate://crates.io/windows_aarch64_gnullvm/0.42.0 \
    crate://crates.io/windows_aarch64_msvc/0.42.0 \
    crate://crates.io/windows_i686_gnu/0.42.0 \
    crate://crates.io/windows_i686_msvc/0.42.0 \
    crate://crates.io/windows_x86_64_gnu/0.42.0 \
    crate://crates.io/windows_x86_64_gnullvm/0.42.0 \
    crate://crates.io/windows_x86_64_msvc/0.42.0 \
    crate://crates.io/ws2_32-sys/0.2.1 \
    crate://crates.io/yansi/0.5.1 \
"



# FIXME: update generateme with the real MD5 of the license file
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = " \
    "

SUMMARY = "Webserver with Rust"t"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

# includes this file if it exists but does not fail
# this is useful for anything you may want to override from
# what cargo-bitbake generates.
include MyRustApp-${PV}.inc
include MyRustApp.inc
```

Comment: You could try compiling using [cross](https://github.com/cross-rs/cross).

Comment: @pigeonhands is there a meta-layer for that purpose?